# How to change/set the block size in Postgres? Is there any file to make the configuration?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I'm looking for the BLOCKSIZE configuration in postgres. I want to know is there a way to change/set the value?

Comment: Hi Rajin, maybe this will help you: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/manually-increase-postgresqls-table-size-limit-of-32-tb

Comment: This can't easily be changed. Why do you think you need that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a different data block size, you would have to recompile PostgreSQL after configuring it with

```sh
./configure --with-blocksize=<size in kB>
```

But I wouldn't recommend doing that, since I have never heard of anybody using that, and there are chances that you uncover interesting PostgreSQL bugs that way.

Comment: are you sure it's correct answer? OP asks for BLOCKSIZE - table block size, which is default 8kB;
SEGSIZE is table segment size, currently 1GB by default;

Comment: @Sebastian You are right; I have edited my answer. Funny that nobody noticed it before.

Answer (score 5):

you need to compile postgres from source, and during configure step pass additional flags with size in kB:

```
./configure --with-blocksize=BLOCKSIZE --with-wal-blocksize=BLOCKSIZE
```

default BLOCKSIZE is 8kB, maximum value: 32kB

after successful installation, you can confirm the current block size by executing:

```
SELECT current_setting('block_size');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is no runtime configuration.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html

> Every table and index is stored as an array of pages of a fixed size (usually 8 kB, although a different page size can be selected when compiling the server).

Comment: Is "page" synonymous with "database block" in Postgre? Those "pages" have nothing to do with _OS pages_ (a.k.a. _virtual pages_ or _memory pages_), correct?