# Index row size 2712 exceeds btree version 4 maximum 2704 for index, while doing DB restore

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to restore a database backup of a Postgresql version 9.2 onto Postgresql 13.5, but while restoring I am getting this message:

> index row size 2712 exceeds btree version 4 maximum 2704 for index

DB restore shows successfull but data is not available once restore is done.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your old database was using a non-standard block size (which is unusual and not recommended), you must be falling victim to this [change in PostgreSQL v12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html#id-1.11.6.14.4):

> In new btree indexes, the maximum index entry length is reduced by eight bytes, to improve handling of duplicate entries (Peter Geoghegan)
>
> This means that a [REINDEX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-reindex.html) operation on an index pg_upgrade'd from a previous release could potentially fail.

You will have to modify the data in your table to be a bit shorter.

An alternative, but not commendable solution is to use [`pg_upgrade`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html) rather than dump and restore. That would leave the index as it is. But then you can never `REINDEX` or dump and restore that database.

Comment: I'm hitting this when doing logical replication from v14.7 to v16.1. I've replicated from v14.7 to v14.7 before. I wonder why this one hit the error. Maybe related to the fact that I used RDS's upgrade function on the v14.7 publisher in the past? The v16.1 subscriber is brand new. Hm.

Comment: @mlissner Try to identify which value (which row) causes the problem.

Comment: The simplest thing was to just delete the index on the subscriber, but we'll implement an MD5 hash key next.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the `SELECT current_setting('block_size');` must have been bigger on your old instance compared to the new one, which causes a [non-key column included in an index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createindex.html#:%7E:text=EXISTS%20is%20specified.-,INCLUDE,included%20in%20upper%2Dlevel%20index%20entries%20used%20for%20tree%20navigation.,-name) to [exceed the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57948262/5298879) when pg_restore inserts the rows. You can restore [only the schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgrestore.html#:%7E:text=%2D%2Dschema%3Dschema,a%20specific%20table.) using `--schema-only` pg_restore option, inspect your indices, temporarily drop them and then safely restore [just the data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgrestore.html#:%7E:text=%2D%2Ddata%2Donly,specifying%20%2D%2Dsection%3Ddata.) with `--data-only`. Indices are not really in the backup, they are rebuilt from scratch during restore - so you can just do it later yourself.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56147727/5298879) is a thread on changing PostgreSQL block size.