# Send a very long query through npgsql.createcommand

Tags: c#, npgsql

I’m trying to send a (very) long query to a PostGreSQL V15 Database using NPGSQL with a code that look like that :

```
string Connection_string = "Host=--:5432;Username=postgres;Password=--;Database=-_-;";

DataSource = NpgsqlDataSource.Create(Connection_string);

string query = "INSERT INTO \"dsf_thdy_process\" values ('Commentaire','long_text',' long_text ',' long_text ',[…],' long_text ')"; // very long query with lot of texts to insert in lot of columns

using (var connection = DataSource.OpenConnection())
{
using var command =DataSource.CreateCommand(query);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}`
```

I get an exception » Npgsql.PostgresException: '54000: the row is to long : length 11392, maximal length 8160' «

If I reduce the length of my query, it’s work.

I tried to add  ‘Write Buffer Size =16000' in the connection string, as explained in https://www.npgsql.org/doc/performance.html  but no effect.

In lost cause, I also tried to add some line return in the query, but still no effect.

Is there a way to increase the length accepted by CreateCommand ? (or another way to send a long query through npgsql)

thanks

Comment: Use parameters. You should do this anyway to avoid SQL injection issues.

Comment: Is the problem that the _command_ is too long or that the _text you're inserting into the column_ is too long?

Comment: @gunr2171 : the command is too long.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, never concatenate a string to be sent, you are WIDE-OPEN to SQL-Injection.  Best parameterize the query.  The following is a SAMPLE of what you would do.

```
var pgCmd = new NpgsqlCommand("");  // not including actual command here.
pgCmd.CommandText = 
@"insert into someTable
( col1,
  col2,
  col3,...
)
values
( :pCol1,
  :pCol2,
  :pCol3,...
)
```

Postgres uses a ":" colon as a parameter indicator.  I also prefix the actual parameter with "p" just to indicate a parameter value, not just inserting a column name.  Helps to prevent ambiguity to me when reading.

Now that you have the command, add the parameters...

```
pgCmd.Parameters.Add( new NpgsqlParameter( "pCol1", someIntegerValue ));
pgCmd.Parameters.Add( new NpgsqlParameter( "pCol2", someStringValue ));
pgCmd.Parameters.Add( new NpgsqlParameter( "pCol3", someDateValue ));
```

Then you can execute the command against whatever connection you have.

Now, it is actually better to explicitly type-case identify the parameters, but look at the overload function instances to help with that.  I see 10 overloads base on what you want to provide.  I actually wrapped a function to add string parameters, date, integer, etc so that would create the parameter, proper type, parameter name and appropriate value.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I still have the issue with the parameterized query. ( still have the exception :  " Npgsql.PostgresException: '54000: the row is to long : length 11392, maximal length 8160' "   .  

If I reduce the length of each string in each 'cell' I want to insert it works, but if I want to insert the full set of data, it fail.

Comment: @Ced_90, that sounds like a table RECORD structure issue.  If you have a text type field that is allocated for 8k bytes, but trying to stuff 20k bytes, the database itself will choke... unless the column itself is defined is unlimited.

Comment: You are probably right, I probably choke a buffer. I was hoping to find which one and increase its size. I finally bypassed the issue by splitting the command in several ‘insert’ query instead of a long one (not very clean, but it’s working). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some other research and testing I found the explanation :  the max size of a row in PostGreSQL is 8160  (block_size).

If you got bigger values, PostGreSQL will use the TOAST mechanism to cope it, but it’s only work for a limited amount of columns  (18 bytes per pointer 8160 bytes max -> 453 columns) and in my case I have 750 columns, therefor the error.

The block_size value can be changed, but it’s not recommanded.

Source : https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/TOAST and [How to change/set the block size in Postgres? Is there any file to make the configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56147727/how-to-change-set-the-block-size-in-postgres-is-there-any-file-to-make-the-conf)